# Personalizar Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Tenho 2 classes, uma que é a Divisão e outra que é Grupo.

No grupo tenho a FK para divisão.

Quero cadastrar um Storage no Admin do Django e no select do Grupo quero que apareça o grupo e a divisão no mesmo select, algo do tipo Grupo 1-Divisao 1 ou Grupo 2- Divisão 1.

Como faço para personalizar o select do admin?

```
class Divisao(models.Model):
    divisao = models.CharField(_('divisao'), max_length=255)


class Grupo(models.Model):
    grupo = models.CharField(_('grupo'), max_length=255)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao, verbose_name=_('divisao'))
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('tipo'))
```

Tentei da seguinte maneira, porém sem sucesso

widgets.py

```
from django.forms.widgets import Select


class DataAttributesSelect(Select):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), data={}):
        super(DataAttributesSelect, self).__init__(attrs, choices)
        self.data = data

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):  # noqa
        option = super(DataAttributesSelect, self).create_option(name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None,
                                                                 attrs=None)  # noqa
        # adds the data-attributes to the attrs context var
        for data_attr, values in self.data.iteritems():
            option['attrs'][data_attr] = values[option['name']]

        return option
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .widgets import DataAttributesSelect
from .models import Storage_Volume
from sss.core.models import Grupo


class StorageVolumeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StorageVolumeAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        data = {'grupo': dict(Grupo.objects.values_list('grupo', 'divisao'))}
        data['grupo'][''] = ''  # empty option
        print(data)

        self.fields['grupo'].widget = DataAttributesSelect(
            choices=self.fields['grupo'].choices,
            data=data
        )
```

admin.py

```
class StorageVolumeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('storages',)
    search_fields = ['storages']
    form = StorageVolumeAdminForm


admin.site.register(Storage_Volume, StorageVolumeAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bianca, se entendi o que você gostaria de fazer, seria algo neste sentido, correto?

[image: Django Admin Select]

Se sim, o que eu fiz para chegar nesse resultado é bem mais simples do que parece, veja:

Apenas escreva o método `__str__` em seus modelos. Este método é chamando sempre que você chama `str(objeto)`. O django usa este método em diversos lugares e mais notavelmente, para exibir um objeto no site de administração do Django, que é onde deseja visualizar neste caso.

Para maiores detalhes, [leia](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#str).

O exemplo abaixo, foi testado com *Python 3.6 e Django 2.0*

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Divisao(models.Model):
    divisao = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.divisao

class Grupo(models.Model):
    grupo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.grupo, self.divisao)

class Storage(models.Model):
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    grupo = models.ForeignKey(Grupo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.storage
```

Como pode ser visto, eu apenas formatei a string de representação deste objeto/modelo (Grupo) para o mesmo passar a exibir o grupo e a divisão a qual pertence.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Adinanp obrigada! Era exatamente isso que queria. Achei que ia ser uma função complexa como a que tentei fazer mas era simples kk Ajudou bastante!!